# MySQL: MAX(date) when there are multiple values for each date

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I record data about marketing results from the different marketing channels (SEM, SEO, Facebvook...). When I add a new piece of data I will record the channel, the date it refers to, how many sales were made and when was this data entered (last_update). Because of the way things are set up it is possible to have to go back and edit the number of sales made at a previous date. I currently do not want to overwrite past data and insert an update as a new line instead. Here below is the DB scheme:

id (int)
channel (small_int)
date (date in unix_time format)
sales (medium_int)
last_update (date in unix_time format)

How would I be able to extract:
- only the latest_update for every channel for every day?
- the same as above but at a date in the past (ie let's imagine I want to see January's data not as it stands today, but as it was entered at latest on February 1st)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this problem would be using [WINDOW FUNCTIONS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html), however MySQL does not provide support for them, so it will require a hack.

Is the id field a foreign key or a meaningless surrogate key identifying each row? I will suppose (because you are using MySQL) that the answer is YES.

```
SELECT
   id,
   channel,
   date,
   sales,
   last_update 
FROM
   my_table a       
JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         channel,
         date,
         MAX(last_update) 
      FROM
         my_table 
      GROUP BY
         channel,
         date
   ) b 
      ON a.channel = b.channel 
      and a.date = b.date 
      and a.last_update = b.last_update;
```

You may create a view with this query.

OBS: If the column id is a meaningless and useless primary key, you should create a proper primary key with date, channel and last_updated columns. Also you should probably avoid using date as a column name as it is a reserved word and the last_updated should be changed from date to date time.

Answer (score 0):

In some pseudo-code: Select the records where last_update = MAX(last_update). In particular,

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable mt1
WHERE mt1.last_update = (
    SELECT MAX(mt2.last_update)
    FROM mytable mt2
    WHERE mt1.channel = mt2.channel
      AND mt2.last_update <= '2015-02-01'
    LIMIT 1
)
```

I assume that for each `channel`, there could be two records with the same `last_update` (i. e. the pair `(channel, last_update)` isn't unique). So `LIMIT 1` chooses an arbitrary one.